# Angular cli shows random numbered minified js files for ng serve dev mode in browser

Tags: angular-cli, angular12

I am using Angular 12 application, after migrating from angular 9, when i did ng serve, I am not able to debug application. JS files are minified and file names are changed as 234.js. Even if I add debugger in typescript files Its been removed while compiling in dev mode.
[image]
Angular.json file content

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "projects": {
    "anomaly-detection": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/anomaly-detection",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/anomaly-detection/src",
      "prefix": "app-anomaly-detection",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/anomaly-detection",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "custom-webpack.config.ts"
            },
            "index": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/assets",
                "output": "/assets/",
                "ignore": ["**/app-info.json"]
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@siemens-di-pa-sw/reusable-components-design-system/resources/css/mdsp-css.min.css",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/styles.scss",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/codemirror.css",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/mindsphere.css",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/material.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection:build",
            "proxyConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/anomaly-detection/src/**/*.ts", "apps/anomaly-detection/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "apps/anomaly-detection/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/anomaly-detection"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:anomaly-detection", "type:app"]
    },
    "anomaly-detection-simulation": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src",
      "prefix": "anomaly-detection",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/anomaly-detection-simulation",
            "index": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/favicon.ico", "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/styles.scss",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/codemirror.css",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/mindsphere.css",
              "apps/anomaly-detection/src/material.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection-simulation:build",
            "proxyConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection-simulation:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "anomaly-detection-simulation:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/tsconfig.app.json", "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "apps/anomaly-detection-simulation/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/anomaly-detection-simulation"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:anomaly-detection-simulation", "type:test-app"]
    },
    "asset-api": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/api",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/api/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/api/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/api/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/api/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/api/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/api/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/api/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/api"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "scope:asset/api", "type:api"]
    },
    "asset-domain-data-access": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/domain/data-access",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/domain/data-access/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/asset/domain/data-access/src/**/*.ts", "libs/asset/domain/data-access/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/domain/data-access/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/domain/data-access/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/domain/data-access/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/domain/data-access"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:data-access"]
    },
    "asset-domain-entities": {
      "root": "libs/asset/domain/entities",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/domain/entities/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/domain/entities/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/domain/entities/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/domain/entities/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/domain/entities/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/domain/entities/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/domain/entities"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:entities"]
    },
    "asset-feature-asset-analyse": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/src/**/*.ts", "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/feature/asset-analyse"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:feature"]
    },
    "asset-feature-asset-anomaly-list": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/src/**/*.ts", "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/feature/asset-anomaly-list"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:feature"]
    },
    "asset-feature-asset-list": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/feature/asset-list",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/feature/asset-list/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/asset/feature/asset-list/src/**/*.ts", "libs/asset/feature/asset-list/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-list/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/feature/asset-list/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/feature/asset-list/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/feature/asset-list"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:feature"]
    },
    "asset-shell": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/shell",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/shell/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/shell/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/shell/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/shell/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/shell/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/shell/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/shell/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/shell"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:shell"]
    },
    "asset-ui-asset-detail-pipes": {
      "root": "libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/ui/asset-detail-pipes"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:ui"]
    },
    "asset-ui-notification-pipes": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/src/**/*.ts", "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/src/**/*.html"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/ui/notification-pipes"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:ui"]
    },
    "asset-ui-trend-data-pipes": {
      "root": "libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/ui/trend-data-pipes"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:ui"]
    },
    "asset-util-chart-configuration": {
      "root": "libs/asset/util/chart-configuration",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/util/chart-configuration/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/util/chart-configuration"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:util"]
    },
    "asset-util-feature-value": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/asset/util/feature-value",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/util/feature-value/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/util/feature-value/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/util/feature-value/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/util/feature-value/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/util/feature-value/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/util/feature-value/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "libs/asset/util/feature-value/src/test-setup.ts"
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/util/feature-value"]
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:util"]
    },
    "asset-util-query-params": {
      "root": "libs/asset/util/query-params",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/asset/util/query-params/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["libs/asset/util/query-params/tsconfig.lib.json", "libs/asset/util/query-params/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "!libs/asset/util/query-params/**/*"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/asset/util/query-params/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/asset/util/query-params/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          },
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/asset/util/query-params"]
        }
      },
      "tags": ["scope:asset", "type:util"]
    },
```

[image]

Webpack config:

[image]